# Pyinstaller one file works in python shell but fails as an exe

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a script that takes a few csv files and concat them, it works as intended when running it in the python shell, but it fails when I make an one file exe with pyinstaller.

This is the error I get when I run my script:
[image: Error message]

The part that seems to fail is this part:

```
# use glob to get all the csv files
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_list= list()

#format columns
dict_conv={'line_item': lambda x: str(x),
           'column_item': lambda x: str(x)}

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:     
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", converters = dict_conv, encoding='latin1') #test latin1
    df_list.append(df)
    #print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])

#add data frames to a list 
RLI_combined = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

This is my whole for context script:

```
# import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime

#Set filename
file_name = 'daglig_LCR_RLI'

# in the folder
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Delete CSV file 
# first check whether file exists or not
# calling remove method to delete the csv file
# in remove method you need to pass file name and type

del_file = path+"\\" + file_name +'.csv'

## If file exists, delete it ##
if os.path.isfile(del_file):
    os.remove(del_file)
    print("File deleted")
else:    ## Show an error ##
    print("File not found: " +del_file)

# use glob to get all the csv files
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_list= list()

#format columns
dict_conv={'line_item': lambda x: str(x),
           'column_item': lambda x: str(x)}

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:     
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", converters = dict_conv, encoding='latin1') #test latin1
    df_list.append(df)
    #print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])

#add data frames to a list 
RLI_combined = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)

#Write date to approval_text
now = datetime.now()
# dd/mm/YY
print_date = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
RLI_combined.loc[:, 'approval_text'] = print_date

#replace value_text with n/a
RLI_combined.loc[:, 'value_text'] = "n/a"

#Sum columns
m = RLI_combined['column_item'].isin(['0030', '0050', '0080'])
RLI_combined_sum = RLI_combined[~m].copy()
RLI_combined_sum['amount'] = RLI_combined_sum.groupby(['report_name', 'line_item', 'column_item'])['amount'].transform('sum')
RLI_combined_sum = RLI_combined_sum.drop_duplicates(['report_name', 'line_item', 'column_item'])

RLI_combined = pd.concat([RLI_combined_sum, RLI_combined[m]])

#export to csv
RLI_combined.to_csv(path + "//" + file_name + '.csv', index=False, sep=";", encoding='latin1')

#Make log    
# Create the directory 
directory = "Log"
parent_dir = path
# Path 
path_log = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory) 

try: 
    os.mkdir(path_log)
    print('Log folder dannet') 
except OSError as error: 
    print('Log folder eksisterer')  

#export to csv
log_name = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")
print(log_name)
RLI_combined.to_csv(path + "//" + 'Log' +"//" + file_name+'_' + log_name + '.csv', index=False, sep=";", encoding='latin1')
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just discovered using the standard pyinstaller and not making it a onefile fixed the issue.  But all those folders are inconvinient for an inexperienced user.

Comment: Good. That is what I meant with: "... running a one-dir *.exe.." (instead of a one-file). You can create a batch file in the top directory which points to the *.exe so you do not have to search for it in all those files/folders

Comment: how do I create a batch that does this?

Comment: Create a text file with two lines: a cd to your pyinstaller-created folder `cd Concat_RLI_components_1.0` and to start the *.exe just type its name in the next line 
`Concat_RLI_components_1.0.exe` save the file with the extension *.bat and put it in the same dir where pyinstaller created the script folder (default would be the "dist"-folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the pyinstaller one file executable you will often ran into problems like that. When starting the *.exe it is extracted to a temporary directory and this is for example the start-location for relative path definitions.
So even if you get your script running and export your *.csv it will often be somewhere on your HD and not at the place of the *.exe where you perhaps expect it to be.

I think in your case the variable df_list stays empty because there are no files listed in csv_files. This is because in the temp dir (location is written in the top of the output) there are no *.csv files.

Please try printing the content of csv_files when running the one-file *.exe if this is the right guess

If this is the case start by running a one-dir *.exe and if this works you know that you have a problem with your path definitions

Comment: I tried adding print(df) in the for loop and print(df_list) before RLI_combined i made. But I still get the same error. maybe it's not what you meant

Comment: I tried printing csv_files in the start of the for loop and in the end aswell

Comment: This printing should just point to the fault / confirm my suspicion, it was not meant that it will solve your problem. Sorry for this misunderstanding